# How to refactor a Windows batch script littered with GOTOs?

Tags: batch-file, refactoring, automated-tests

I have to maintain a batch script of about `3500` lines littered with `GOTO`. Seems that the original "developer" hasn't heard of **[this famous paper](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html)** and **modular programming**.

### What the script does?

The script deals with the (silent) installation/uninstallation/reinstallation of several programs using different options. It could be split in several files that deal with each program in part. The problem is that if you're trying to take a part in another file that part will still `GOTO` another section that needs to be in the original script.

### Refactoring?

Normally you wouldn't do a refactoring without having automated tests (so you can be sure you didn't break anything), but I don't know how to do it. There's no testing framework for that.

### Partial Solution

I have come up with a partial "solution" that is some kind of adaptation of [characterization tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterization_test) (from [Working Effectively with Legacy Code by Michael Feathers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)) and [approval tests](http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000801.html):
- create another script: `test.py` that replaces all commands (like copy or msiexec) with echo,
- redirect the output to a text file (`good.txt`),
- change the original batch script,
- run the `test.py` script again and save the output to another text file (`current.txt`),
- diff `good.txt` and `current.txt` -> if there are no differences then I didn't break anything, but if they are different I need to check if I broke something.

### Problem with partial solution

How can I capture and replace all the commands? I could make a list of commands to replace, but there are also a lot of string concatenations to get the name and path of the program to be installed.

### CMD level capture/hook?

Is there any way I can hook into the command line interpreter (`CMD.exe`) so I can replace on the fly all the calls to installers with `echo`?

### Other suggestions?

Do I approach the problem in the wrong way? Can I do it better somehow? Do you have some advice I could use?

Comment: Before I took the time to refactor, rewrite, and re-test, I'd ask myself if it's actually broken/difficult to maintain or is just (mostly) aesthetically ugly.  I'll take ugly functional code over not-as-well-tested pretty code.

Comment: Unfortunately that script is hard to maintain. And let's not forget the Boy Scout Rule (for coders): "Always check a module in cleaner than when you checked it out."

Answer (score 2):

You could replace all `COPY`, `DEL` or  `CALL` with `%COPY%`, `%DEL%` ,...

So you can use the same file for production and also for the tests.

```
@echo off
if not defined UNITTEST (
  set "COPY=COPY"
  set "DEL=DEL"
  set "CALL=CALL"
)

%COPY% src dest
%DEL% somefile.txt
%CALL% installer.exe
```

And from your unittest.bat, you could start it via

```
@echo off
set "COPY=>>trace.log ECHO COPY"
set "DEL=>>trace.log ECHO DEL"
set "CALL=>>trace.log CALL ECHO "
del trace.log
set "unittest=Active"
call production.bat
fc good.txt trace.log
```

Comment: Nice approach :) I didn't know about `fc` (file compare). I tried it and prefer to use a full fledged diff tool (like `p4merge`). The situation with the batch script is a bit more complicated: it depends on access to the registry (which I don't know how to take out) and various variables are set and reset during the execution (not at the beginning of the script).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in Batch, but I have done my fair share of it. With that said, I can offer a few tips.

- Forget trying to do it all at once. Batch is very hard to debug. Echoing out to a log file helps a lot, but it will not capture everything you need if something goes wrong.
- Work on breaking out the exe and msiexec calls into self-contained scripts. It is much easier to test the small script for the functionality you desire. Once you have that working, it is simple to call that script from the "Master" script.
- Establish a good protocol for passing args to, and return codes from the smaller scripts. If there are common settings needed to be used for all the scripts consider using a central settings file.
- GOTOs are not the devil, unless they pass control all over the place. Normally there are two good reasons that I know of to use GOTO’s.

  1. Skip past a block of code that does not need to run.
  2. To SET values into variables. Note there is a bug that can prevent variables from having their value set from within an 'IF' statement block. That little bug caused a big headache for me at one time.

  Calls to a label might be better option at times.
- Depending on how far back the legacy support is required, consider using Powershell when possible. The power and debugging capabilities of Powershell far out way the benefits of simple scripting of Batch. Which at 3500 lines simplicity has already been lost. You are already looking at Python, so maybe that could be used instead.
- If you need a break point, use Pause. ECHO all the settings you need to examine right before the pause. This is as close to a break point I have found for batch.
- Echo the command you intend to run to a log file and actually run it.
- Write small verification scripts to be used independently or with the “Master” script to confirm you are getting the results you are expecting.
- Use the right tool for the job. I like to use EditPadPro, RegexBuddy, and BeyondCompare for batch editing and comparing differences. There free tools that can be used too NotePad++ and Windiff. Making many edits in a file of that size is best handled by a good editor.  IE inserting an echo at the beginning of a line that calls a cmd.exe.
- Remember it is scripting not programming. While there is a lot of overlap of the two, the same exact approach to a problem may not be viable between the two.
- Always make a backup copy of the scripts as a whole before mucking around. A fallback position is greatly appreciated when there is one small bug that you can’t find.
- If it ain't broke... well you wouldn't be working on it if everything was working just fine.
- Always test changes. And when you are done test it again. After that have someone else test it.
- Just my .02. I’m sure someone else can chime in with more advanced advice. My knowledge on Batch has been acquired from the school of hard knocks, supplemented by ss64.com